# WPF: Get position of child UIElement within its parent. Ignore RenderTransform if any

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, panel, rendertransform

Lets say I have this XAML code:

```
<DockPanel Name="pan">
    <Label Content="AAA" Name="lab1" />
    <Label Content="BBB" Name="lab2" />
    <Label Content="CCC" Name="lab3" />
</DockPanel>
```

I my code behind I want to find out what are the coordinates of `lab2` within `pan`. **Hovewer** I want to ignore any present RenderTransform of `lab2`. So the solution must return same coordinates for above code and following:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Label Content="AAA" />
    <Label Content="BBB" >
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform Y="20"/>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
    <Label Content="CCC" />
</DockPanel>
```

In another words I want the position that was set by the `ArrangeOverride` method of `pan` when calling `Arrange` on `but2`. I would call it 'logical position'. The 'visual position' can be obtained by calling following method:

```
private Point visualPoss() {
    Point lab2Vis = lab2.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    Point panVis = pan.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    return new Point(lab2Vis.X - panVis.X, lab2Vis.Y - panVis.Y);
}
```

But this is not a solution of my problem as the return value of this `visualPoss()` is not equal for both XAML code examples above.

Please leave comment if somehing is unclear.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there is very simple and clear solution:

```
private Point logicalPoss() {
    Vector vec = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(lab2);
    return new Point(vec.X, vec.Y);
}
```

It looks like it is working well. If you know abou the scenerio when it will not work please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you! Absolutely counter-intuitive method name but works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I would get the transform, and convert it to a `MatrixTransform`. You can then use the Inverse property to reverse the render transform. It would look something like so:

```
private Point visualPoss() 
{
    Point lab2Vis = lab2.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    Point panVis = pan.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

    if (lab2.RenderTransform != null)
    {
        var matrix = new MatrixTransform(lab2.RenderTransform.Value);
        lab2Vis = matrix.Inverse.Transform(lab2Vis);
    }

    return new Point(lab2Vis.X - panVis.X, lab2Vis.Y - panVis.Y);
}
```

Comment: one tweak... you probably want to walk all the way up the visual tree and apply the inverse of each rendertransforms you encounter

Comment: Good point for a general method. Since the element is a child of the panel that he is concerned about comparing, I didn't think it was necessary in this case.

Comment: I'm sorry to dissapoint you but I have tryied something very similar to this and it did not work - the only defference is that I created inverse transformation right from the original like this: `lab2.RenderTransform.Inverse.Transform(lab2Vis)`. I don't know why, but it did not translate the coordinates back to the original location.