# WPF: Get the real 'logical' position of Child within its parent Panel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

Another problem in my WPF questions series :)

I'm creating custom `Decorator` that will be used to decorate `Panel`s (or it can be Behavior, no difference).

That `Decorator` deals with elements that are in that `Panel` (`Children` property of the `Panel`). It attaches some `RenderTransform`s to those elements. Now I need a position of some element ('child' of the `Panel`) relative to the `Panel` itself. In other words I need a position if some child element in the `Panel`s coordinate space. in just another words I want the offset that was specified by the `ArrangeOverride` method of the `Panel` when calling `Arrange` method on `Children`.

That seem to be easy. But I cannot find the way to always get *right* coordinates.

This code

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(child)
```

does not work when the panel is inside `ScrollView` - it takes topmost, leftmost visible corner of the `Panel` as an origin of coordinate space - not the real topmost and leftmost corner of the `Panel`.

The code

```
Point position = child.TransformToAncestor(panel).Transform(new Point(0,0));
```

will not work when some render transforms are already active on the child element of the `Panel`.  It will return the position of transformed image(by the render transfrom) of child element. The render position.

The same problem is with this aproach:

```
Point panelPosition = panel.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
Point childPosition = child.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
Point position = new Point(childPosition.X - panelPosition.X, childsPosition.Y - panelPosition.Y);
```

So this i what I have tryied but it did not work. I have 2 similar questions on this topic that were tying to simplify the problem, so I got some of suggestions above. Now I introduced the problem in its full complexity, I hope to get the right advice.

If something is unclear please leave the comment.
Thank you

Comment: If you use Canvas panel you can call Canvas.GetTop and Canvas.GetLeft to determine the top and left coordinates on the 2D plane.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know what type my `Panel` is. It is given to me, the `Decorator` should be able to decorate any `Panel`.

Comment: OK, I am not sure as of now but check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760310/wpf-get-position-of-child-uielement-within-its-parent-ignore-rendertransform-if

Comment: @bjoshi: That is one of my questions about this topic that I mentioned in this question. Sadly, it does not help :(

Comment: Can this be solved as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923697/how-can-i-get-the-position-of-a-child-element-relative-to-a-parent ?

Answer (score 0):

You can "undo" the `RenderTransform` before calling `TransformToAncestor`:

```
Point origin = child.RenderTransform.Inverse.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
Point position = child.TransformToAncestor(listBox).Transform(origin);
```

Comment: Sadly this also does not work. `TransformToAncestor` takes as a beginig of coordinate space left top **visible** corner...